# Left Join retornando apenas 1 registro para cada relacionamento

Tags: sql, join

Preciso fazer um Join entre 2 tabelas onde preciso apenas que seja apresentado o ultimo registro da 2ª tabela (apena 1 registro da tabela 2 para cada registro da tabela 1).

```
SELECT a.Campo1, a.Campo2, a.Campo3, a.Campo4, b.Campo1, b.Campo2
FROM Tabela1 a
LEFT JOIN Tabela2 b ON b.Campo1 = a.Campo1 AND  (b.Campo2 = (SELECT b.Campo2 FROM Tabela2 c  WHERE c.Campo1 = a.Campo1) AND ROWNUM = 1)
```

tentando dessa maneira retorna o erro:

> ORA-01799: uma coluna não pode ser externamente unida a uma subconsulta

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: O que há de errado com `SELECT a.Campo1, a.Campo2, a.Campo3, a.Campo4, b.Campo1, b.Campo2 FROM Tabela1 a LEFT JOIN Tabela2 b ON b.Campo1 = a.Campo1`? Não entendo qual é a finalidade desse subselect e pelo que vejo, me parece completamente inócuo e desnecessário.

Comment: Um `having` junto com o agrupamento não resolveria?

Comment: O select em questão retorna mais de 1 registro da 2ª tabela, eu preciso apenas do ultimo registro gravado nesta tabela.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Veja se assim funciona:

```
SELECT a."Campo1"
     , a."Campo2"
     , a."Campo3"
     , a."Campo4"
     , b."Campo1"
     , b."Campo2"
  FROM Tabela1 a
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT MAX(Tabela2."Campo2") AS "Campo2"
                  , Tabela2."Campo1" 
               FROM Tabela2 
              GROUP BY Tabela2."Campo1") b ON b."Campo1" = a."Campo1"
```

Comment: Da um erro, identificador inválido.

Comment: Acredito que seu banco seja *Case Sensitive*, veja agora... (Editei a resposta).. pq testei aqui e funcionou corretamente.  
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/294d85/1/0

Comment: Ocorre o mesmo erro

Comment: Esse é o SQL que vc precisa, como você pode ver no link http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/294d85/1/0 ele está funcionando (ao menos sua lógica está certa). Talvez falte algum detalhe, tente colocar as aspas como no link... mas a lógica é essa

Comment: Deu certo, muito obrigado pela ajuda.