# Trazer apenas um registro num left join mesmo que hajam mais registros na relação

Tags: sql, microsoft-access

Olá, como vai?

Está é minha query:

```
SELECT cf.id_clifor, 
       cf.nome, 
       lv.localvenda, 
       ed.cidade, 
       ctt.telefone, 
       cf.descontoglobal, 
       lv.id_localvenda 
FROM   ((tbl_clientes_fornecedores AS cf 
         INNER JOIN tbl_local_de_venda AS lv 
                 ON cf.id_localvenda = lv.id_localvenda) 
        LEFT JOIN tbl_enderecos AS ed 
               ON cf.id_clifor = ed.id_clifor) 
       LEFT JOIN tbl_contatos_clientes AS ctt 
              ON cf.id_clifor = ctt.id_clifor 
WHERE  (( ( cf.status ) = 'ATIVO' )) 
ORDER  BY cf.nome;
```

Os resultados são assim:

[image: Assim são os resultados]

A questão é que na tbl_contatos_clientes e tbl_enderecos, pode ter mais de um telefone/endereço, mas eu gostaria que os resultados me retornassem apenas 1 único registro.
Tentei DISTINCT e mais algumas coisas mais sem sucesso. Eu uso ACCESS.

Obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: então precisa agrupar, o `group by` vai resolver isso, veja isso, pode ajudar: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/228296/57220

Comment: boa, deu certo, obrigado

Comment: Veja resposta aqui.
Resolveu pra mim. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/277691/left-join-retornando-apenas-1-registro-para-cada-relacionamento